# Combine two cron-scheduling intervals in a single DAG

Tags: cron, airflow

**Rewrite of the question:**

Using [airflow](/questions/tagged/airflow), I would like to schedule a process to run every two hours from 2 till 10 am and a single time at 22:30. The `schedule_interval` parameter accepts a cron-expression, but it is not possible to define a single cron-expression to achieve the above scheduling. Currently, I did:

```py
dag = DAG(process_name, schedule_interval='30 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,23 * * *', default_args=default_args)
```

But this will execute the process every 30 minutes past the hour, and this every 2 hours from 2 till 23.

Is there a way I can combine two cron-schedules in Airflow?

```
0 2-10/2 * * *
30 22 * * *
```

**Original question:**

I have `2,4,6,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 00 * *`

I need to have `23, 30` in my schedule, but I don't want 2-22 to be run at the 30 min interval.

Comment: Are you making use of the Linux cron-scheduler (crontab) or something completely different. A java-based solution or something else?

Comment: @kvantour The solution is going to be a string in a DAG.py script implemented in Airflow.   `dag = DAG(process_name, schedule_interval='30 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,23 * * *', default_args=default_args)`

Comment: Hi Josh, I have rewritten the question a bit in the way I understand it. If this new version does not reflect what your original question, feel free to [revert the edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289108/how-to-revert-rollback-a-edit-suggestion).

Comment: Looks good to me @kvantour

Comment: I hope somebody can help you out here. Sorry that I can't.

Comment: No worries.  Fingers crossed. @kvantour

Answer (score 1):

So, I realized, it is not possible!

Comment: Do you have a solution? I'd love to implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use two cron expressions for the same DAG (Might change in the future if [PR: Add support for multiple cron expressions in schedule_interval](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/24733) is accepted)

Starting Airflow >=2.2.0:
It is possible to get custom time based triggering using custom [Timetable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/timetable.html#timetables) by [customizing the DAG scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html) to match what you expect.
To do so you need to [define the scheduling logic](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html#define-scheduling-logic) by implementing `next_dagrun_info` and `infer_manual_data_interval` functions - Airflow will leverage this logic to schedule your DAG.
You can view an example can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/example_dags/plugins/workday.html).